# Python to Ruby: How do I open a file, parse the data and multithread with it?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I need to translate this into Ruby:

```
ids = [i.strip() for i in open('ids.txt','r')]
proxies = [i.strip() for i in open('socks.txt','r')]
for (i,j) in izip(ids,proxies):
    i = parseID(i)
    j = j.split(':')
    threading.Thread(target=raider,args=(i,j)).start()
```

This is just showing you what's happening with it:

```
def parseID(auser3):
auser3 = auser3.split('&')
userid = auser3[1].split('=')[1]
k1 = auser3[2].split('=')[1]
k2 = auser3[3].split('=')[1]
return [userid,k1,k2]
return l5

def raider(a3,p):
global ip
global port
try:
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, p[0], int(p[1]))
    socket.test = socks.socksocket
    xat = socket.test(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.SOL_TCP)
    xat.connect((ip,int(port)))
    xat.send('<y r="'+str(info[2])+'" />\0')
    bypass = xat.recv(1024)
    print "\nRecv --> "+bypass+"\n"
    rcv = tree.fromstring(bypass.strip("\0"))
    if 'i' not in rcv.attrib:
        raise Exception("YUP")
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(a3)
    print p[0]+":"+p[1]+"\n\n"
    uid = a3[0]
    k = a3[1]
    Y = getY(rcv.attrib["au"], rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[0],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[1],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[2],rcv.attrib["p"].split("_")[3], rcv.attrib["i"])
    j2 = str('<j2 cb="'+rcv.attrib["c"]+'" Y="'+str(Y[0])+'" l5="'+str(Y[1]).strip()+'" l4="583" l3="463" l2="0" q="1" y="'+rcv.attrib['i']+'" k="'+k+'" k3="0" p="0" c="'+str(info[2])+'" f="0" u="'+str(uid)+'" d0="0" n=" " a="0" h="" v="0" />\0')
    xat.send(j2)
    print "\nSend --> "+j2+"\n"
    while 1:
        text = xat.recv(4069)
        if 'logout' in text or 'idle' in text or 'dup' in text:
            raider(a3, p)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            xat.send('<m t=" " u="'+uid+'" />\0')
except:
    raider(a3, p)
```

I made an attempt but it failed:

```
def raid()
    $proxies = []
    $ids = []
    IO.foreach('ids.txt') do |line| # Foreach id as a line 
        $ids << line #ine.scan(/&Userid=(.*?)&k1=(.*?)&k2=([0-9]+)/i) # parse id
    end
    IO.foreach('socks.txt') do |line|
        $proxies << line
    end
    $test = $ids.zip($proxies)
end
```

It reads the data from the two files, matches each ID with a Proxy, and sends it to a function.

Comment: How is your attempt failing?

Comment: It's just not doing what I want it to, It's suppose to match a ID with a Proxy and send it to a function

Comment: `data`, is thrown away after each of the loop is completed, you probably want to store it somewhere, for reuse

Comment: I've tried that but even when data isin't thrown away it doesn't do what I want it to.

Comment: Anyone? .. I'm stuck on this

Comment: Don't use `$global` variables unless you understand when and why you should use them.

Comment: Also, when you want help, it's important to supply both sample input data, and your expected output. Without that you're expecting us to create whatever data makes sense to us, and whatever output we want. At that point an answer submitted has to be modified to fit in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like:

```
def raid()
  ids = File.readlines('ids.txt')
  proxies = File.readlines('socks.txt')
  ids.zip(proxies).map{ |a| a.map(&:chomp) }
end
```

Starting with two files:

- socks.txt:

  ```
  127.0.0.1
  127.0.0.2
  ```
- ids.txt:

  ```
  foo
  bar
  ```

Calling the above method returns:

```
raid() # => [["foo", "127.0.0.1"], ["bar", "127.0.0.2"]]
```

> "...sends it to a function"

I'm not sure where in your code you tried to call a function, so I can't replicate that.